# assigning dynamic cursor style to element using jquery in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opera, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to dynamically change the cursor style when the mouse is over an element. The cursor should be either "move" or "default" depending on a boolean returned by a method.
The code is something like this:

```
$("#elemId").mousemove(function(event) {
    if(cursorShouldBeMove()) {
        $(this).css({'cursor':'move'});
    } else {
        $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
    }
}
```

This code works like a charm in IE8,FF3,Chrome and Safari.
Only Opera fails to handle it correctly.

I'm using Opera 9.6.4

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

---

I prepared a sample for testing;

```
var cursorStatus = true;
setInterval(function() { cursorStatus = !cursorStatus; }, 500);

function cursorShouldBeMove() {
  return cursorStatus;
}

$(function() {
  $("#elemId").mousemove(
    function(event) {
      $(this).css("cursor", cursorShouldBeMove() ? "move" : "default");
    }
  );
});
```

If you move your mouse from outside of #elemId to inside of it for a few times you will see that the cursor will change. But if you position your mouse in #elemId and move your mouse, cursor not changes.

The code is very simple. I think it's a bug of Opera.

I tested this code also with;

- Firefox 3.5.1 (worked)
- Internet Explorer 7 (worked)
- Google Chrome 2.0 (worked)
- Safari 3.2 (worked)

(Windows versions)

Answer (score 3):

Opera is real funny with cursors. I find that you have to move the mouse over the element twice before it actually works.
Can see [here](http://pastebin.me/60b0ae9b9019a5f070d79886d1ee6d14) that you need to hover over the Hello World twice to get the cursor to change.

Same issue described [here](http://www.1-script.com/forums/Opera-and-cursor-pointer-CSS-article115306--2.htm)